# Embed file after codesign signature is created

Tags: macos, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

I create a macOS bundle and codesign it. Post codesigning I want to sign app binary and put the resulting signature inside the bundle. 
My research says its not possible, is there slight chance that its possible to do so? Mavericks and older you could exclude files from bundle signature but not sure if its possible in Sierra/Yosemite/El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Code Signing In Depth Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG302)

## I exclude files so I can fix my bundle after I build it?

*This is no longer allowed. If you must modify your bundle, do it before signing. If you modify a signed bundle, you must re-sign it afterwards.*

Codesigning recursively goes to the sub directories and include all the code while generating signature and modifying the bundle (removing file, adding new file or changing even 1 bit in the files included in the signature) will invalidate the bundle.